# recovering programmatically the ServingUrl of a blob uploaded in BlobStore using the BlobInfo?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I want to recover the ServingUrl of a blob uploaded  in BlobStore using the  BlobInfo entity

My code in My doGet() method is :

```
        ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();

        Iterator<BlobInfo> iterator = null;
        iterator = new BlobInfoFactory().queryBlobInfos();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if(iterator.next().getFilename().equals("test.png"))
            { resp.getWriter().println(iterator.next().getBlobKey()) ;//  the result is  <BlobKey: aKQyp27ZfDgvEdPE8QvMAQ>
             resp.getWriter().println(iterator.next().getFilename());//the result is test.png
            BlobKey bk=iterator.next().getBlobKey();
            String urlStr=imagesService.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(bk));
            resp.getWriter().println(urlStr);
            }
        }
```

I got this error :

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /enrollementfinale. Reason:

```
INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

Caused by:

java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.next(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:75)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.next(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobInfoFactory$1.next(BlobInfoFactory.java:108)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobInfoFactory$1.next(BlobInfoFactory.java:100)
    at com.EnrollementFinaleServlet.doGet(EnrollementFinaleServlet.java:135)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.__handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:490)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Powered by Jetty://

i will be very grateful if you help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved , it was caused by the 2 lines:

```
resp.getWriter().println(iterator.next().getBlobKey());
resp.getWriter().println(iterator.next().getFilename());
```